# Samba's "inherit permissions" does not inherit modes for other

Tags: permissions, samba

I have a share with "inherit permissions = yes". I have a directory in the share with mode rwxrwsr-x. If I create a subdirectory, the modes are rwxrws---. The same happens with a parent directory with mode rwxrwxr-x (resulting in rwxrwx---).

The permissions of the newly created subdirectory are independent of the OS used to create them and apparently independent of the umask when using smbfs (mount.cifs).

The following is an excerpt from **smb.conf** and contains everything related to permissions, modes, etc. of the share.

```
    force group = +mi
    inherit permissions = yes
    inherit owner = yes
    nt acl support = no
```

I added "nt acl support = no" for testing purposes and it does not seem to make a difference.

Does "inherit permissions" not work for non-user, non-group modes?

Comment: You also need to consider the values of `directory mask` and `force directory mode`, either of which might be affecting your results.  Set them explicitly and see if your results change.

Comment: `force directory mode = 0777` seems to have fixed the problem. Permissions are now inherited correctly, as far as I can tell. I will do some more testing, though.